# CentOS 7 mounted windows share is read only

Tags: windows, samba, centos7, network-share, mount

I mounted a Windows share on CentOS 7, but I have read only access to it. I need write access.

Commands used to mount the share...

```
sudo mkdir /media/shared
sudo chmod 777 /media/shared
sudo vim /etc/fstab
//192.168.16.25/shared /media/shared cifs 
username=XXXX,password=XXXX,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

It mounts fine, but the owner is now "admin" and it's read only...

```
$ ls -lrt
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 admin admin 4096 Aug  7 18:11 shared
```

And I can't change it

```
$ sudo chown -R root shared
chown: changing ownership of ‘shared/System Volume Information’: 
Permission denied
sudo chown: changing ownership of ‘shared’: Permission denied
$ sudo chmod 777 shared
chmod: changing permissions of ‘shared’: Permission denied
```

What am I missing? And on the Windows Server, the drive is shared with "Everyone" with full access.

Fixed! Here is the solution to what I changed the config to in fstab...

```
//192.168.16.25/shared /mnt/shared cifs username=XXXX,password=XXXX,uid=0,gid=0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Comment: Do you have `yum install samba-client samba-common cifs-utils` installed? If not, after installation and re-mount does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read up on file ownership and permissions in the [mount.cifs manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs), which is part of the cifs-utils RPM package:

> ## File And Directory Ownership And Permissions
>
> The core CIFS protocol **does not provide unix ownership information** or mode for files and directories. Because of this, files and directories will generally appear to be owned by whatever values the `uid=` or `gid=`options are set, and will have permissions set to the default `file_mode` and `dir_mode` for the mount. Attempting to change these values via chmod/chown will return success but have no effect.
>
> ...

Basically you are using the mount options `uid=1000,gid=1000` to force a specific owner of the mounted share, which is what makes your `chown` command fail.
If you want to change the owner, simply mount the share with the correct owner in the  `uid=?,gid=?` mount options in `/etc/fstab`  instead of using `chown` and use `file_mode=?` and `dir_mode=?` instead of `chmod`.

Comment: That worked. I added the actual solution to my question. Thanks!